# how to pass variables into session array in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

after executing query **search.php**,multiple results appears with own info(title,description,url).

```
result_1,result_2,result_3......
```

when i click on url,next page **final.php** opens. how should i store that result info in variable and display it on **final.php**.
I tried session variables,but it only passes last result info i.e `result_3` to next page.

here's my code

**search.php**

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
  $_SESSION['description'] = $description;
  $_SESSION['content_url'] = $url;
  $_SESSION['icon'] = $icon;
  ?>
```

**final.php**

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    $session_title  = $_SESSION['title'];
    $session_description = $_SESSION['description'];
    $session_url = $_SESSION['content_url'];
    $session_icon = $_SESSION['icon'];
  ?>
```

Comment: put session_start() at start of every pages then try

Comment: that was the first thing i did,but it just passing the last result info

Comment: i think you need to use multi-dimension array because may be in search you are getting more than one result and you want to display all results right?

Comment: use multi-dimensional session array to find the solution

Comment: i am little confused with multidimensional array,can you give me little idea about how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put `session_start();` on top of each file you were using the session variables.

To make a array session variable you can do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["array"][] = array(
    "title"         => $title,
    "description"   => $description,
    "content_url"   => $url,
    "icon"          => $icon
);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

# Optional clear session, remove line if you don't want to
session_unset($_SESSION);
?>
```

Above code will output something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["array"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["content_url"]=>
      NULL
      ["icon"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

In final.php you can check this by doing:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["array"])) {
    foreach($_SESSION["array"] as $result => $key) {
        echo $key["title"];
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: yeah i already did it but forgot to mention in code,session variables is passing on other page but problem is it only passes last result info only

Comment: Make sure then you have the updated code in your question otherwise people here keep saying that you forgot the `session_start()` :)